# Missing 1033 Directory in SharePoint 2010 URLs

Tags: migration, upgrade, language

I seem to be missing a '1033' directory for my SharePoint 2010 installation.  Here's the full details:

We upgraded from SP2007 to SP2010 using the database attach method.  Some resources have a 1033 folder in their URL (for instance, the Documents link on a site collection points to sharepoint.domain.com/_layouts/1033/viewlsts.aspx), but this does not exist on the server.  I installed the English Language 1033 pack and it says it was successful and it shows as being installed on the server, but URLs still don't work.  If I take out the 1033 the URL works but it's built in to so many places we need to get it working.  It worked fine on the SharePoint 2007 server.  The error message I get is:

The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /_layouts/1033/viewlsts.aspx

Again, if I remove the 1033 the URL works fine.  How can I make SharePoint interpret this URL correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Did you manually add that link? Looks like the only viewlsts.aspx I can find resides directly in the /_layouts/ directory. It's possible that the old viewlsts.aspx was localized and was replaced in 2010 by a generic viewlsts.aspx containing resource strings.

Comment: No, that's the link that is used in the Quick Launch bar.  You're correct that the file only resides in _layouts.  On the 2007 server the URL has the 1033 in it if you hover, but when you actually click the link the URL it takes you to does not have the 1033.  It seems to know to redirect/ignore it.

Comment: -1. This is irrelevant answer - far removed from reality, reeks lack of experience, and adds just more noise to an already well know  topic in realm of SharePoint migrations that OP enquired about.

Answer (score 2):

"NavNodes" tables in Database are having Global and Current navigations references which are showing reference of 1033 in their URLs, so need to delete this ‘`/1033`’ text from all URLs. Reference of ‘`/1033`’ is used only in SharePoint 2003. This is not more in use in MOSS 2007 and SP2010.

Steps to update Navigations URLs in MOSS 2007 or SP2010:

1. Open SQL Management Studio
2. Select newly migrated database and click on New Query.
3. In New Query wizard at right side, copy following SQL script (shown in script) and execute it.

   ```
    UPDATE [DatabaseName].[dbo].[NavNodes]
    Set URL = '_layouts/viewlsts.aspx'
    where URl = '_layouts/1033/viewlsts.aspx'

    UPDATE [DatabaseName].[dbo].[NavNodes]
    Set URL = '_layouts/settings.aspx'
    where URl = '_layouts/1033/settings.aspx'

    UPDATE [DatabaseName].[dbo].[NavNodes]
    Set URL = '_layouts/create.aspx'
    where URl = '_layouts/1033/create.aspx'

    UPDATE [DatabaseName].[dbo].[NavNodes]
    Set URL = '_layouts/mtgredir.aspx'
    where URl = '_layouts/1033/mtgredir.aspx'
   ```

Database update step should be followed by `IISRESET` on all WFE servers.

Once you update the URL value you should activate ‘‘PublishingPrerequisites’ and then ‘PublishingResouces’ features for each site using STSADM utility:

Steps:

1. Click Start, click Run, type cmd in the Open box, and then click OK.
2. Go to command prompt and locate 12 hive folder.
3. Run following command for each migrated sites.

> stsadm.exe -o activatefeature –filename “PublishingPrerequisites\feature.xml” -url  -force
>
> stsadm.exe -o activatefeature –filename “PublishingResources\feature.xml” -url  -force

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have never known viewlsts.aspx or any other system application page to exist in or be directed to the Layouts localised folders.

The only files that normally reside there are javascript and image files.

`viewlsts.aspx` is a server side page which contains its own tokens to get localised strings from the resource files, using standard ASP.NET techniques as the page is compiled. There is no need for a localised version of this file.

The reason you could be seeing the 404 is because a resource on that page (such as a localised javascript file) is being requested by a control and can't load it, so throws the exception which bubbles up to the page.

I would attempt a rebuild of the entire Web Front End (perform a re-install, and re-run the config wizard) and reattach to your farm.

Comment: Your should be banished from IT industry with views such as "rebuild of the entire Web Front End (perform a re-install, and re-run the config wizard) and reattach to your farm" when you have no clue about the question at hand!

Answer (score 1):

Hi had the same issue with this. I resolved it by manual updating the top link bar as follows:

1. Click site settings (you will have to remove the 1033 folder in your url link)
2. Click Top Link Bar under Look and Feel
3. Select each link and manually remove the 1033 folder and save.

Hope this is of some use

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to this issue. 
It is just a question of missing Files in Dir 1033. Copy the files form /layout/ to /layout/1033 and you should be good to go

Comment: This is not a recommended solution, as it would have to be replicated on each web front end, this step would have to be logged for support, and again repeated each time a web front end needed to be rebuilt, and a subsequent service pack could undo the action. Too must risk involved with this solution.

Comment: James, I tried this option just to keep things rolling on the test environment. I have the same issue  in all the server (Dev, test, staging). and i have tried to re built it twice. The complete scenario is that we are upgrading from Sharepoint 2003 to SP 2010. There are many Custom feild.. is there a better way to do it???.. Thanks K

Comment: You are migrating via SharePoint 2007 yes? There is no direct migration path without the use of third party tools.

Comment: yes we did it through a Virtual migration environment (Via 2007). Attach and upgrade method for the content database.

Comment: I would next check the masterpage then. It might be that your upgraded site is still using an SPS2003 Quick Launch Data Source Control.

Comment: Well, The master page has a data source which might link to the wrong location. but we have 1500 sites. so i will have to go and change the master files for all of them?.. i am more curious where are the loop holes in migration

Comment: Yes, though if all use the same masterpage, and if you want to go ahead and adopt the look & feel of 2010, you can probably use powershell to write a script to iterate over all the sites and reset the masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the IIS Rewrite Module?  You could have a rule that looks at any url with /_layouts/1033/ and rewrite it to /_layouts/ .  That should allow you continue to use the 1033 folder within URLs without having to move or change anything within SharePoint.